# Pass a Ctrl-C to the prompt in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, mercurial

I'm trying to write a shell script to reproduce a situation I encountered when using Mercurial's shelve extension.

This requires interrupting out of a prompt provided by Mercurial's command line user interface (UI). See the following script

```
rm -rf test-shelveinterrupt
hg init test-shelveinterrupt
cd test-shelveinterrupt

hg branch foo
echo "First line of foo" >> foo
hg add foo
hg ci -m "First line of foo" foo
echo "Second line of foo" >> foo
hg shelve

hg up null

hg branch bar
echo "First line of bar" >> bar
hg add bar
hg ci -m "First line of bar" bar

hg unshelve

pkill -INT shelveinterrupt
```

If you run this script as

```
bash shelveinterrupt.sh
```

, it will end with

```
file 'foo' was deleted in local [working-copy] but was modified in other [shelve].
You can use (c)hanged version, leave (d)eleted, or leave (u)nresolved.
What do you want to do?
```

which is the response of the `hg unshelve` command at the end of the script.

I want to break out of this prompt with an interrupt. The last `pkill` is intended to interrupt the shell process, but of course it won't be called while the script is waiting on input. Is there a way to call this without creating a second script to call the first one?

Note that after interrupting the script, you'll get

> unresolved conflicts (see 'hg resolve', then 'hg unshelve --continue')

Comment: What Mercurial are you using? Because when I try with release 5.7, it complains that it does not know what `hg topics` is: `hg: unknown command 'topics'`.  I also do not get the prompt that you mention.  Needless to say, I'm not a Mercurial user.  You may want to show how you set up a similar environment to what you are using, so that us `hg` noobs could give this question a go (because I don't think it's an issue that _requires_ deep `hg` knowledge to solve).

Comment: @Kusalananda Oops. My bad. topics belongs to the Evolve extension, which has to be installed separately. Though any branch like thing will work, so I guess I could redo it with named branches. Does `hg shelve` work?

Comment: It recognizes `shelve` as a valid sub-command, yes.

Comment: Expect would be one possible answer... (I’m too busy right now to write it up.)

Comment: Replaced `hg topics` with `hg branch`. And the rebase is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I want to do can be accomplished with the Tcl
extension, expect. However, this requires two scripts.

A shell script.

```
#################################
shelveinterrupt.sh
#################################
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf test-shelveinterrupt
hg init test-shelveinterrupt
cd test-shelveinterrupt
hg branch foo
echo "First line of foo" >> foo
hg add foo
hg ci -m "First line of foo" foo

echo "Second line of foo" >> foo
hg shelve

hg up null

hg branch bar
echo "First line of bar" >> bar
hg add bar
hg ci -m "First line of bar" bar

hg log -vG

hg branch

hg unshelve
```

And an Expect script.

```
#################################
shelveinterrupt.exp
#################################
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./shelveinterrupt.sh
expect "What do you want to do?"
send -- "^C"
expect eof

# Check `hg status
cd test-shelveinterrupt
set hgst [exec hg status]
puts $hgst
exec hg update .
```

This produces the following output

```
faheem@orwell:~/test-mercurial$ ./shelveinterrupt.exp
spawn ./shelveinterrupt.sh
marked working directory as branch foo
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
shelved as foo
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
marked working directory as branch bar
unshelving change 'foo'
rebasing shelved changes
file 'foo' was deleted in local [working-copy] but was modified in other [shelve].
You can use (c)hanged version, leave (d)eleted, or leave (u)nresolved.
What do you want to do? interrupted!
# The repository is in an unfinished *update* state.

# Unresolved merge conflicts:
#
#     foo
#
# To mark files as resolved:  hg resolve --mark FILE

# To continue:    hg update .

abort: outstanding merge conflicts
(use 'hg resolve' to resolve)
    while executing
"exec hg update ."
    (file "./shelveinterrupt.exp" line 11)
```

So `hg update .` doesn't work either.